# What is the best strategy for a human to physically sort a pile of cards?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic

Suppose one has a **physical** pile of cards. Each card is labelled with a number, which were annotated. As an actual example, I have a pile of 560 cards in that exact order:

```
[36, 32, 30, 21, 73, 90, 9, 24, 81, 27, 65, 15, 53, 82, 28, 43, 45, 21, 41, 69, 38, 39, 6, 17, 67, 20, 54, 37, 65, 18, 38, 14, 68, 73, 30, 4, 13, 39, 3, 14, 36, 68, 18, 4, 82, 43, 1, 18, 41, 71, 24, 70, 1, 4, 23, 39, 20, 28, 30, 37, 39, 41, 49, 79, 43, 22, 55, 70, 3, 22, 28, 82, 3, 12, 70, 24, 54, 78, 19, 49, 41, 27, 41, 67, 10, 23, 24, 20, 27, 44, 80, 70, 41, 6, 21, 20, 48, 73, 54, 1, 7, 67, 38, 26, 66, 30, 43, 36, 55, 16, 24, 27, 28, 43, 28, 1, 3, 9, 38, 19, 88, 65, 68, 21, 44, 36, 6, 39, 67, 6, 69, 49, 56, 39, 49, 41, 50, 18, 82, 17, 22, 47, 68, 18, 24, 53, 51, 68, 53, 65, 1, 7, 7, 38, 55, 55, 16, 67, 82, 78, 70, 1, 20, 30, 54, 73, 78, 82, 20, 20, 22, 27, 30, 32, 65, 78, 44, 9, 12, 31, 3, 70, 24, 4, 54, 3, 28, 39, 49, 55, 66, 69, 70, 9, 21, 24, 54, 71, 13, 6, 67, 38, 22, 50, 36, 30, 1, 12, 9, 24, 44, 48, 54, 78, 3, 21, 32, 56, 66, 68, 70, 82, 80, 10, 28, 28, 29, 41, 43, 43, 45, 43, 74, 55, 2, 50, 74, 38, 67, 27, 51, 67, 38, 36, 11, 70, 41, 6, 65, 39, 49, 4, 17, 41, 27, 6, 10, 56, 82, 55, 66, 73, 78, 73, 55, 70, 3, 68, 67, 20, 54, 15, 25, 43, 49, 54, 68, 79, 69, 24, 55, 78, 37, 74, 73, 3, 67, 30, 65, 18, 53, 31, 38, 39, 38, 2, 16, 39, 6, 67, 80, 20, 66, 14, 27, 9, 36, 47, 21, 41, 1, 24, 54, 56, 11, 70, 1, 19, 4, 17, 30, 36, 38, 38, 44, 67, 36, 19, 65, 27, 30, 15, 36, 21, 41, 69, 9, 38, 65, 68, 21, 36, 14, 17, 68, 18, 24, 44, 74, 73, 54, 1, 1, 31, 49, 24, 55, 78, 73, 3, 10, 68, 73, 30, 7, 23, 82, 43, 2, 70, 27, 54, 80, 68, 73, 30, 47, 79, 51, 38, 39, 6, 67, 20, 54, 67, 6, 39, 13, 49, 41, 27, 56, 66, 18, 24, 6, 9, 67, 65, 27, 82, 20, 78, 25, 23, 50, 81, 20, 27, 70, 47, 41, 6, 24, 28, 43, 28, 51, 70, 1, 39, 78, 68, 10, 74, 21, 20, 3, 73, 54, 30, 2, 78, 9, 73, 37, 47, 21, 30, 65, 79, 23, 18, 37, 20, 53, 41, 67, 6, 4, 18, 39, 49, 41, 57, 28, 8, 55, 48, 1, 39, 20, 7, 27, 70, 41, 30, 20, 41, 16, 67, 6, 39, 25, 8, 49, 18, 82, 19, 55, 12, 70, 8, 55, 44, 3, 65, 11, 2, 3, 54, 9, 78, 22, 71, 50, 39, 49, 18, 22, 13, 82, 55, 36, 29, 15, 27, 28, 28, 49, 39, 9, 18, 9, 78, 68, 44, 21, 20, 3, 50, 29, 7, 82, 20, 78, 66, 32, 30, 43, 82, 43, 1, 23, 49, 24, 55, 37, 9, 22, 38, 65, 68, 20, 21, 36, 12, 18, 41, 43, 14, 28, 82, 3, 6, 25, 81, 21, 41]
```

My question is: given such list, what is the best algorithm for an human to execute that will sort the list least possible amount of quick human moves? By quick human move, one can visualize the cards are stacked in a table, so a person can either move 1 card from a pile to another (up to a small finite limit of possible simultaneous piles), or place an entire pile on top of another (as this obviously should count as a single movement).

Comment: I assume you only move from the top of the deck?

Comment: Yes, only from the top of a pile to the top of another.

Comment: So the human knows there are 560 cards, and the values lie between 1 and 90?

Comment: Exactly, 560 cards with values between 1 and 90. In that order specifically.

Comment: The larger problem is finding solution strategies for deterministic puzzles. Search algorithms for this are a significant part of AI courses. You can get a fair bit from the first videos from the [MIT OpenCourseware AI course](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-034-artificial-intelligence-fall-2010/index.htm). Of course for specific puzzles, puzzle-specific rules often allow more efficient solutions than general-purpose search methods - or at least better heuristics to guide and narrow the search.

Comment: I may have misread your question. Are you saying that the order of the cards is known to the person sorting the cards? That would mean he knows there are only 65 different values, and he would know how many cards of each value there are. This could significantly improve the results.

Comment: Yes, I wondered if that information could help pre computing an optimal sort to apply physically.

Comment: Just the knowledge of the holes in the range reduces the problem to "sorting values in the range 1-65" instead of 1-90. And knowing that the first card with value N come after all cards with value N+1 means you can use one stack for the two values in the numbered stacks algorithm. I'll have another look at it tonight.

Comment: My idea is that a computer would brute force the specific configuration until it finds the optimal sequence of movements an human has to perform (given a fixed number of stacks). That is, you give: `prepareSort(3, [4,1,2,5])` (3 is top) and it returns something like: `move 0 1; move 0 2; move 0 2; move 0 1; move all 1 2;`  which would execute `[4,1,2,5] [] [] → [1,2,5] [4] [] → [2,5] [4] [1] → [5] [4] [1,2] → [] [4,5] [1,2] → [] [] [1,2,4,5]`. That is, ideally the human shouldn't read the cards, just execute movements.

Comment: That said, I also wanted to know about an algorithm for a human to sort a list that isn't known, which you gave a great answer for, so I just accepted it. I'll edit my question to fit your answer, and I'll ask again the question of finding an optimal set of movements in a better phrased way.

Comment: @Viclib I added a better method which I think is close to optimal when the number of distinct values is known; with a few tweaks based on the initial ordering of the cards in the example, it requires only 1158 actions for 12 stacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumptions**

The person sorting the cards has the following information:

- The values on the cards are in the range 1 to 90.
- The number of cards is greater than 90, so there will be duplicates.
- Some values in the range may be missing.
- The number of stacks that can be used.

**91 stacks: one stack per value**

The best case scenario is obviously the one where there is enough space on the table for the unsorted stack plus as many stacks as there are different values. In this case, every card is put on a stack according to value, after which stack 89 is put on top of stack 90, stack 88 is put on top of stacks 89, and so on until there is one ordered stack. The number of required actions equals the number of cards plus the number of seperate values (560 + 64 in the example).
The person doesn't know whether there will be any values missing from the range, so he can only use this strategy if there is space for 91 stacks.

**33 stacks or less: ordered sub-stacks**

If there isn't enough space for 91 stack, the following strategy could be used:

- Take the fist card and use it to start a new stack.
- Take every following card, and either:

  - Put it on top of the first stack whose top card is equal to or lower than the card.
  - Start a new stack if the card is lower than any of the top cards
- If you run out of space to create new stacks, merge the stacks into an ordered stack by repeatedly taking the highest top card from the stacks and putting it on top of the ordered stack.
- Start splitting the rest of the unordered stack again, this time ordering the new stacks in the other direction, so that you end up with stacks with the lowest value on top, which can be merged with the ordered stack from the previous round.
- Repeat this until only one stack remains.

For the example array, this algorithm can be done in one go if there is space for 33 stacks (1 input stack, 1 ordered stack, 1 empty place to merge stacks, 30 ordered sub-stacks). This would take 560 + 560 actions; it's obviously less efficient because all the cards have to be moved one by one at least twice.

The number of rounds depends on whether you start by sorting up or down; for the example array, down seems to be the best choice. With unknown input, the best choice cannot be known in advance; the difference is never more than 1 round, though.

**Numbered stacks**

The method mentioned above with 91 stacks can be adapted for fewer stacks. You use the available space for sub-stacks for the N highest values, and put the lower values on an unordered stack. When all cards have been moved, you stack the numbered sub-stacks, and start again with the unordered stack as the input stack. Every round you look for N lower values, until you've done the whole range. The advantage over the previous method is that the sub-stacks are moved per stack, and not per individual card. The results are better, except for the range 33 to 39.

This is the number of rounds and actions per total number of stacks:

```
        | ORDERED SUB-STACKS (UP FIRST / DOWN FIRST) |     NUMBERED STACKS
stacks  |  rounds         actions         per card   | rounds actions  per card

91       1       1     1120    1120      2.0     2.0      1     624      1.1
...
48       1       1     1120    1120      2.0     2.0      2     973      1.7
...
40       1       1     1120    1120      2.0     2.0      3    1111      2.0
39       1       1     1120    1120      2.0     2.0      3    1125      2.0
38       1       1     1120    1120      2.0     2.0      3    1159      2.1
37       1       1     1120    1120      2.0     2.0      3    1207      2.2
36       1       1     1120    1120      2.0     2.0      3    1226      2.2
35       2       1     1674    1120      3.0     2.0      3    1247      2.2
34       2       1     1635    1120      2.9     2.0      3    1263      2.3
33       2       1     1559    1120      2.8     2.0      3    1280      2.3
32       2       2     1521    1644      2.7     2.9      4    1318      2.4
31       2       2     1512    1627      2.7     2.9      4    1344      2.4
30       2       2     1504    1607      2.7     2.9      4    1368      2.4
29       2       2     1458    1518      2.6     2.7      4    1408      2.5
28       3       2     1945    1499      3.5     2.7      4    1455      2.6
27       3       2     1923    1473      3.4     2.6      4    1501      2.7
26       3       3     1905    1999      3.4     3.6      4    1560      2.8
25       3       3     1883    1979      3.4     3.5      5    1629      2.9
24       3       3     1822    1899      3.3     3.4      5    1697      3.0
23       4       3     2255    1802      4.0     3.2      5    1788      3.2
22       4       4     2206    2286      3.9     4.1      5    1854      3.3
21       4       4     2070    2197      3.7     3.9      5    1880      3.4
20       5       5     2441    2512      4.4     4.5      6    2037      3.6
19       6       5     2876    2410      5.1     4.3      6    2165      3.9
18       6       5     2659    2313      4.7     4.1      6    2247      4.0
17       7       7     3021    2804      5.4     5.0      7    2350      4.2
16       7       8     2926    3071      5.2     5.5      7    2500      4.5
15       8       9     3302    3546      5.9     6.3      8    2680      4.8
14      12      11     4686    4363      8.4     7.8      9    2930      5.2
13      14      13     5241    4729      9.4     8.4      9    3187      5.7
12      16      17     5481    5826      9.8    10.4     10    3458      6.2
11      19      18     6262    5985     11.2    10.7     12    3900      7.0
10      24      23     7679    7421     13.7    13.3     13    4385      7.8
 9      32      33    10477   10719     18.7    19.1     15    5038      9.0
 8      41      40    12187   12130     21.8    21.7     18    6030     10.8
 7      54      55    16464   16488     29.4    29.4     23    7427     13.3
 6      82      83    25293   25326     45.2    45.2     30    9784     17.5
 5     150     151    42225   42230     75.4    75.4     45   14529     25.9
 4     334     335    93301   93305    166.6   166.6     89   28717     51.3
 3       -       -        -       -       -       -       -       -       -
```

UPDATE:

**Sub-ranges of varying size**

A better version of the numbered stacks method would be to split the unordered stack into sub-ranges, and subsequently split each sub-range into numbered stacks and add them to the ordered stack. With each sub-range that is processed, an additional stack space is freed, so the ranges can become increasingly large.

In the example, the highest cards are put on seperate stacks, lower cards are lumped together in ranges, down to the lowest cards which are part of an eleven-value range (1-11). The required number of stacks to run this algorithm in one go is the number of values in the biggest range plus one, thus 12 in the example.

Taking into account the original version of your question, which asked for an efficient sorting method for a list with a known initial order, I have used knowledge of the cards in the stack to make a few additional optimizations to the example:

- **Number of distinct values**: although the cards are in the range 1-90, only 65 distinct values are present. This reduces the problem to sorting cards in the range 1-65 with no values missing. In the example, I use the values 1-65 for simplicity.
- **Seperation of adjacent values**: there are a few values for which every card of value N comes before or after every card of value N+1. This is used in the case of 24/25, where the single 25-card is temporarily put on top of the 24-stack, and in the case of 48/49, where a single stack is used because the cards are already in the right order.

Using this method, and knowledge of the initial order, the number of required actions for a table with **12 stacks** is **1158 actions**, which is much lower than the 5826 actions (or 33 stacks) and 3458 actions (or 38 stacks) required by the ordered sub-stacks or numbered stacks methods.

The following diagram shows the value or range of values of the cards in each of the 12 stacks. Every line shows a step in the algorithm, and in the column on the right you'll find the number of actions required to reach this step.

```
  1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12
                                                                                    ACTIONS
                     1-65
 65     64     63           62-59  58-54  53-47  46-40  39-32  31-22  21-12  11-1      560
65-63                       62-59  58-54  53-47  46-40  39-32  31-22  21-12  11-1        2
65-62   61     60     59           58-54  53-47  46-40  39-32  31-22  21-12  11-1       25
65-59                              58-54  53-47  46-40  39-32  31-22  21-12  11-1        3
65-58   57     56     55     54           53-47  46-40  39-32  31-22  21-12  11-1       42
65-54                                     53-47  46-40  39-32  31-22  21-12  11-1        4
65-53   52     51     50    49-48   47           46-40  39-32  31-22  21-12  11-1       73
65-47                                            46-40  39-32  31-22  21-12  11-1        5
65-46   45     44     43     42     41     40           39-32  31-22  21-12  11-1       52
65-40                                                   39-32  31-22  21-12  11-1        6
65-39   38     37     36     35     34     33     32           31-22  21-12  11-1       96
65-32                                                          31-22  21-12  11-1        7
65-31   30     29     28     27     26    24+25   23     22           21-12  11-1       82
65-22                                                                 21-12  11-1      8+1
65-21   20     19     18     17     16     15     14     13     12           11-1       82
65-12                                                                        11-1        9
65-11   10      9      8      7      6      5      4      3      2      1               91
65- 1                                                                                   10
                                                                                      ----
                                                                                      1158
```

In general, with unknown initial sorting, 12 stacks will sort N cards with a maximum of 66 distinct values (11 + 10 + 9 + ... + 1), and the number of actions is `N + (N - #66) + 10 + 9 + 8 + ... + 1` where #66 is the number of cards with the highest value (because these don't have to be moved twice).

```
  1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12  <-STACKS
                                                                                   ACTIONS
       1-66
66            65-64  63-61  60-57  56-52  51-46  45-39  38-31  30-22  21-12  11-1        N
66-65   64           63-61  60-57  56-52  51-46  45-39  38-31  30-22  21-12  11-1   #65-64
66-64                63-61  60-57  56-52  51-46  45-39  38-31  30-22  21-12  11-1        1
66-63   62     61           60-57  56-52  51-46  45-39  38-31  30-22  21-12  11-1   #63-61
66-61                       60-57  56-52  51-46  45-39  38-31  30-22  21-12  11-1        2
66-60   59     58     57           56-52  51-46  45-39  38-31  30-22  21-12  11-1   #60-57
66-57                              56-52  51-46  45-39  38-31  30-22  21-12  11-1        3
66-56   55     54     53     52           51-46  45-39  38-31  30-22  21-12  11-1   #56-52
66-52                                     51-46  45-39  38-31  30-22  21-12  11-1        4
66-51   50     49     48     47     46           45-39  38-31  30-22  21-12  11-1   #51-46
66-46                                            45-39  38-31  30-22  21-12  11-1        5
66-45   44     43     42     41     40     39           38-31  30-22  21-12  11-1   #45-39
66-39                                                   38-31  30-22  21-12  11-1        6
66-38   37     36     35     34     33     32     31           30-22  21-12  11-1   #38-31
66-31                                                          30-22  21-12  11-1        7
66-30   29     28     27     26     25     24     23     22           21-12  11-1   #30-22
66-22                                                                 21-12  11-1        8
66-21   20     19     18     17     16     15     14     13     12           11-1   #21-12
66-12                                                                        11-1        9
66-11   10      9      8      7      6      5      4      3      2      1           #11- 1
66- 1                                                                                   10
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a least to most significant digit bucket sort, basically emulating a card sorter. There are 10 bins, numbered 0 to 9, to place the cards in, and one input stack of cards to be sorted, face up. The person takes a card from the top of the input stack and places it face down into the bin corresponding to least significant digit. Once all the cards have been placed into bins, the 10 stacks of cards in the bins are removed from the bins, starting with bin 9, ending with bin 0, stacked face up. The process is repeated again, this time using the most significant digit, and after the second pass, the cards are sorted (and this method is stable, preserving the order of equal cards).

On a real card sorter, all cards are effectively placed face down, so the operator grabs cards from the bins from 0 to 9, placing them effectively face down back into the card sorter's input tray.

It would be possible to have 90 bins and sort in one pass, but I think that would be difficult for a human to deal with.

Comment: Would this method be adaptable to a smaller table that doesn't hold 11 stacks?

Comment: @m69 - For a smaller table, a vertical matrix of bins (opening in the front facing the human) could be used to hold 10 of the stacks, similar to the way mail used to be sorted in the old days.

Comment: Great out-of-the-box thinking there, rcgldr.